# Docker isn't updating the container of a service in compose after image it's based on was updated

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a baseimage with some app stuff I rarely update. Then I have an image which is more often updated that uses that baseimage (with `FROM` in the Dockerfile). Finally I have a docker-compose on a production server which composes several services by using the app image url (url to a self hosted registry). The services have different env variables and commands.

When I need to update a service on production, I only build the app image (not the baseimage). After that, I push the new image to the registry and tag it twice, once with a timestamp and once with 'latest'.

Then I go into the production server and `docker-compose pull` the image and finally I `docker-compose up -d`.

My expectation is that the image of the service is updated, but when I `exec -it <id> bash` into the service I don't see the files updated like they should.

The new image is definitely pulled though, because when I `run -it <id> bash` into the image I see the updated files.

Answer (score 0):

Start the stack using `docker-compose up --build -d` otherwise if the `projectname_service` image already exists it will just run it and not rebuild the layers it needs to. And if the base image is updated it should have a new tag that you should update your `FROM` statement at the top to trigger a full rebuild of the image